# mac osx shows fat partitions on sd card, windows not - why?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, partitioning, u-boot

I have an SD card which was partitioned using uboot. The card is used to boot an ARM board I've been working on. Besides the rootfs, I've created a bunch of fat32 partitions on the card to store user data.

[image: partition layout of sd card]

I want to read/write to/from the partitions on mac osx and windows. On mac osx, I can see the partitions and I get no complaints that the card should be formatted.

On windows, I don't see any partitions and I get a popup dialog box saying the card should be formatted. Is there a way to make windows show the fat32 partitions like mac osx does and not complain about the card?

[image: pop on windows 10, part 2]
[image: popup on windows 10, part 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a well known fact that Windows treats removable drives as only one partition.

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1068420/partitioned-flash-drive-only-first-partition-can-be-seen-in-windows) for detailed explanation.